# Graph Neural Network - Node level regression

Tags: prediction, pytorch-dataloader, attention-model, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I am trying to train a graph neural network model and I am having problems regarding the models' architecture. What I have is DataBatch objects that comes from `torch_geometric.data` library.
In batch object(data), every row in data.y is target variables for nodes in every graph. Batch consists of node embeddings coming from 128 different graphs.What I am interested in is the prediction of first node in every graph and I am not sure how to proceed. I read that graph attention networks are specifically used for node level regression.

```
DataBatch(x=[2634, 768], edge_index=[2, 2506], edge_attr=[2506, 1], y=[128, 131], mask=[128, 131], batch=[2634], ptr=[129])
```

Here is what I have as architecture

```
class GCNAttentionModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, dropout_rate):
        
        #super(GCNModel, self).__init__()
        super(GCNAttentionModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GATConv(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.conv2 = GATConv(hidden_dim, output_dim)

        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        
        
    def forward(self, x, edge_index, edge_attr,batch):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index, edge_attr)
        x = torch.nn.LeakyReLU()(x)
        #x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout_rate, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index, edge_attr)
        x = torch.nn.LeakyReLU()(x)
        #x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout_rate, training=self.training)
        return x
```

The first level output has the size of `torch.Size([2634, 131])` and I am not sure if it is what it is supposed to be if I am interested in specific nodes' prediction. Can anyone help or suggest me a way?

Comment: Something with your phrasing is a bit unclear to me... "What I am interested in is the prediction of first node in every graph" - what is first node? In the order they appear originally? Graph are somewhat unordered so it is a bit confusing (at least to me).

If you only need prediction for one node in each graph, maybe you should do a graph regression (as opposed to node regression)? Have a single y value (tensor of size 1) for each `Data` object and take it as the prediction of that specific node you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Graphs are unordered, that's correct. Data objects are stored as in batch: `DataBatch(x=[2634, 768], edge_index=[2, 2506], edge_attr=[2506, 1], y=[128, 131], mask=[128, 131], batch=[2634], ptr=[129])` Here, every row in y represents a graph and size of (1x131) are target variables for every node in one graph. What I have is target variables for all nodes and first I wanted to train a model that predicts on node level and later on I will do a graph regression by considering the node that I am interested. In short, this GAT model will be used to improve node embeddings.

Comment: From my understanding, which is minimal, when working on a node level you will need your y to have a cell for each node, so you will want y to be of size [2634, N]. That way you can do prediction for each node. Though I am not it matches what you are trying to do... If you are still want to go from 2634 to 131, you will have to do some polling (I think). E.g. [global_mean_pool](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.nn.pool.global_mean_pool.html)